# Why is tarball being recognised with .tar extension in GET Request

Tags: linux, webserver, tar, headers

So I have a question about header requests on filetype..

Not sure of the best way to phrase the question, so I will explain what I have done.

Created a tarball on a server, `tar-cvf alle.tar.gz ./folderX`

That's all perfect. Now I transferred it to my www directory to share it conveniently with a colleague.

```
sudo mv ./alle.tar.gz /var/www/
```

Great no problem.

When I go to the http://host.tld/alle.tar.gz it works perfectly. 
HOWEVER
When I go to http://host.tld/alle.tar (not full extension) it ALSO works.

As you can see the dir absolutely does not contain a file of alle.tar

[image: Dir Contents]

Why is this and is it anything to be concerned about?

Comment: Many browsers support automatic compression (and **decompression**).

Comment: So this is a browser feature as opposed to being served by the server ?

Comment: I suspect that your web-browser and your web-server have a mutual understanding and that the result is clippy-style-helpful. Looking at the specs now because my own understanding of this is enough to know that it is possible and that web-servers can gzip data (on the fly or pre-gzipped), but no more.

Comment: I'd try grabbing it from the .tar url with `lynx` at the command line and see if you get the same results.  Or `wget`.  If it's the server doing it, it'll work, and if it's the browser, it most certainly won't (at least with both of them...I wouldn't put it past a modern `lynx` build to actually include this feature if it's simple enough, especially with a pipe).

Comment: Take a look in your apache "mime.types" config file and see if you have anything for .tar.gz listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `alle.tar` works in addition to `alle.tar.gz` is due to web server features such as [Apache Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html), as you can see by the examples on the page:

```
Filename        Valid hyperlink     Invalid hyperlink
foo.html.en     foo                 -
                foo.html            
foo.en.html     foo                 foo.html
foo.html.en.gz  foo                 foo.gz
                foo.html            foo.html.gz
foo.en.html.gz  foo                 foo.html
                                    foo.html.gz
                                    foo.gz
foo.gz.html.en  foo                 foo.html
                foo.gz
                foo.gz.html
foo.html.gz.en  foo                 foo.gz
                foo.html
                foo.html.gz
```